# Does author of LaTeX documents need xparse or \ExplSyntaxOn?

Tags: macros, expl3, xparse

If an "end-user" is preparing documents with LaTeX and using the current version of LaTeX(as of now, LaTeX2e <2021-06-01> patch level 1), which automatically loads L3 programming layer <2021-10-12>, and if the user is writing and applying macros that use `\NewDocumentCommand`, etc., is there any reason to either:

1. include `\usepackage{xparse}`, or
2. use `\ExplSyntaxOn` ?

As, for example, in the following source derived from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/393188/13492:

```
\documentclass{article}

\NewDocumentCommand\test{o}{\IfNoValueTF{#1}{test}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\test[hello], and \test[hello]{\ world!}
\end{document}
```

I am aware, of course, of discussions such as those in [What do ExplSyntaxOn and ExplSyntaxOff do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108696/what-do-explsyntaxon-and-explsyntaxoff-do/108703#108703), but I am asking a practical question from a document writer's point of view, not from the point of view of a package author or LaTeX developer!

Comment: `xparse` was included in the kernel release of 2020-10-01, I think. And you only need to enable `\ExplSyntaxOn` (and then `Off`) in your document if you are including `expl3` code in it (meaning, directly, not inside a package).

Comment: In one sense, you need `\ExplSyntaxOn` if you're trying to write some macro that needs expl syntax.  So I think the answer ends up being, "it depends on what you're wanting to do in your document".

Comment: 1. No. 2. Only if the document author needs to write expl3 code. The `\ExplSyntaxOn`, `\ExplSyntaxOff` switches handle changing the category codes of `_`, spaces, etc, which otherwise would be treated as math mode commands, glue, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know a recent LaTeX is available then you only need to explicitly use

```
\usepackage{xparse}
```

If you want to use one of the features that were trialled in the `xparse` package but were not included in the final version (`ltcmd`) that was incorpoated into the format. Notably the `g` argument type. But `g` is evil so hopefully you won't need that.

`\ExplSyntaxOn` is like `\makeatletter`, it was never needed to access commands such as the `\IfNoValueTF` that you show, but just as `\makeatletter` allows occasional access to commands with `@` in their name (which would be better in package code rather than the document), `\ExplSyntaxOn` allows access to commands with `_` and `:` in their names (and some control over white space) again to access code that would probably be better in a package but can be placed in the preamble if needed.